# PDO inserting only last Bound parameter

Tags: php, pdo

Ive written a pdo wrapper class with a query function to automatically take an array and bind the values to the statement before execution.

```
public function query($query, $sprints = NULL)
{
    // Add query to the last query and benchmark
    $bench['query'] = $query;

    // Prepare the statement
    $this->result = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

    // Process our sprints and bind parameters
    if(is_array($sprints))
    {
        // Bind our parameters
        foreach($sprints as $key => $value)
        {
            // if we are using "?'s", then we up the keys +1
            if(is_int($key)) ++$key;

            // Bid the param based on its type
            if(is_int($value))
            {
                // Bind the param
                $this->result->bindParam($key, $value, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $bench['bound'][$key] = $value;
            }
            else
            {
                // Bind the param
                $this->result->bindParam($key, $value, \PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($value));
                $bench['bound'][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    // Time, and process our query
    $start = microtime(true);
    try {
        $this->result->execute();
    }
    catch (\PDOException $e) { 
        // show error
    }
    $end = microtime(true);

    // Get our benchmark time
    $bench['time'] = round($end - $start, 5);

    // Get our number of rows
    $this->num_rows = $this->result->rowCount();

    // Add the query to the list of queries
    $this->queries[] = $bench;

    // Return
    return $this;
}
```

The problem is, on an Insert, its replacing all the ?'s with the last bound parameter. Here the query and results:

```
INSERT INTO sessions(`token`,`ip_address`,`last_seen`,`user_data`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The bound params are:

```
[bound] => Array ( [1] => test1 [2] => 0.0.0.0 [3] => test3 [4] => test4 )
```

And the result in the database, is all 4 columns are filled with test4. Anyone have a clue as to why its doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno what's your problem but why not to make it just

```
$this->result = $this->pdo->prepare($query); 
$this->result->execute($sprints);
```

Comment: Well ive been alittle confused about that. Do the parameters still get cleaned from swl injection this way?

Answer (score 2):

Use bindValue, not bindParam.

```
<?php
if ( count( $this->_params ) > 0 )
    {
        foreach ( $this->_params as &$param )
        {
            $statement->bindValue( ":{$param->name}", $param->value, $param->type );
        }
    }
```